# Project management tables (with cost "spread sheets") using spreadtab

Tags: tables, calculations

I'm trying to create a simple project management table detailing costs per task and milestone, using spreadtab:
[image]

The code for the latter is:

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXllr}}
\toprule
@ \textbf{Task} & @ \textbf{Description} & @\textbf{Duration} & @\textbf{Hours} & @\textbf{Cost} \\
\midrule
@ 1         & @ \textbf{Foobar development} &  @ 4 weeks                    & 200 & \\
@ 1a        &   @ Doing this and that                   & 1         &  [-1,0]*35 & [-1,0]*200 \\
@ 1b        &   @ Reading papers                        & 2         &  [-1,0]*35 & [-1,0]*200 \\
@ 1c        &   @ Writing documents                     & 1         &  [-1,0]*35 & [-1,0]*200 \\
@ 2         &   @ \textbf{Acme development}     & @ 4 weeks     & 200  & \\
@ 2a        &   @ Writing Acme                                  & 2     &  [-1,0]*35 & [-1,0]*200 \\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}
@ \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Total}} & sum(c2:[0,-1]) & sum(d2:[0,-1]) & sum(e2:[0,-1]) \\
\end{spreadtab}
```

At the moment, I'm trying to figure out the best method to:

- Make task input easier, avoiding code duplication for each row.
- Automatically generate totals for the milestone row, from its subtasks.
- Allow per-document or per-table settings for the hourly rates and hours-per-week.
- Automatically formatting milestone descriptions to be bold.
- Bonus: use fractions when the amount of weeks has non-zero decimals.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use an external program like MSProject and export the table to LaTeX.